# Как реализовать progress bar как в примере

Tags: android

Как реализовать Progress Bar, что представлен в примере?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почитайте о горизонтальном прогрессбаре. В сети очень много подробных нюансов о нем расписано.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю для данного примера  подойдет  эта библиотека:

https://github.com/lingochamp/MagicProgressWidget

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Идеально! Спасибо большое

Answer (score 2):

TextView( со стрелкой) - ProgressBar - TextView (отображение количества "всего из"). Все заворачиваете в ViewGroup располагающий элементы в одну строку. Ну и дальше в ваш Layout.